# matchMedia not present when testing create-react-app component which contain react-slick?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I tried to create testing file for my existed project which was build by

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

But i got this error when i ran `npm test a`

```
FAIL  src/__tests__/movie_single/MovieSingle-test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    matchMedia not present, legacy browsers require a polyfill

      at Object.MediaQueryDispatch (node_modules/enquire.js/dist/enquire.js:226:19)
      at node_modules/enquire.js/dist/enquire.js:291:9
      at Object.<anonymous>.i (node_modules/enquire.js/dist/enquire.js:11:20)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enquire.js/dist/enquire.js:21:2)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-responsive-mixin/index.js:2:28)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-slick/lib/slider.js:19:29)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-slick/lib/index.js:3:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/movie_single/MovieDetailsBox.js:4:45)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/movie_single/MovieSingle.js:3:50)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/movie_single/MovieSingle-test.js:3:46)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.642s
Ran all test suites matching "a".
```

So this is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-stylus": "0.10.0",
    "concurrently": "3.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "0.6.1",
    "stylus": "0.54.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "watch": "concurrently --names 'webpack, stylus' --prefix name 'npm run start' 'npm run styles:watch'",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  }
}
```

And this is my `MovieSingle-test.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MoviesSingle from '../../components/movie_single/MovieSingle';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    ReactDOM.render(<MoviesSingle />, div);
});
```

So how can i fix this and at least make the common react component test passed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 33):

Add a `src/setupTests.js` to your project (which will be executed before running your tests):

```
/**
 * fix: `matchMedia` not present, legacy browsers require a polyfill
 */
global.matchMedia = global.matchMedia || function() {
  return {
      matches : false,
      addListener : function() {},
      removeListener: function() {}
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that works out of the box for Ionic 5

Answer (score 6):

I had just run into it as well, here is what helped me:

Get the `test-setup.js` from [here](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/blob/master/test-setup.js) and place it to the `src` directory

```
window.matchMedia = window.matchMedia || function() {
    return {
        matches : false,
        addListener : function() {},
        removeListener: function() {}
    };
};
```

Add the following to the `package.json`

```
"jest": {
    "setupFiles": ["<rootDir>\\src\\test-setup.js", "<rootDir>\\config\\polyfills.js"]
  },
```

See if that helps.

Comment: "jest": {
    "<rootDir>\\src\\test-setup.js", "<rootDir>\\config\\polyfills.js"
  }
is not a valid json format.

Comment: USE like below, meanwhile pollyfills should be first

=====> "setupFiles": ["<rootDir>\\config\\polyfills.js", "<rootDir>/config/testSetup.js"],

Answer (score 5):

Add this piece of code:

```
window.matchMedia =
    window.matchMedia ||
    function() {
        return {
            matches: false,
            addListener: function() {},
            removeListener: function() {}
        };
    };
```

in jest.setup.js or setupTests.js (you can check the name from jest.config.js
eg. setupFiles: ["./jest.setup.js"] )

Answer (score 2):

if it is an existing project,
you have to install one package called polyfill as dev dependency by using the following command
**npm i polyfill --save-dev**
here is the link of that package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/polyfill

after installing,
if there is setupTests.js file or else setup it in src folder
in that paste this

```
/**
 * fix: `matchMedia` not present, legacy browsers require a polyfill
 */
var polyfill = require("polyfill");

global.matchMedia =
  global.matchMedia ||
  function () {
    return {
      matches: false,
      addListener: function () {},
      removeListener: function () {},
    };
  };
```

it worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me, without pollyfill, in a new TS CRA App w/ Chakra UI

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GatsbyJS, place the code from @maow inside the loadershim.js file in your root directory.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the following steps to resolve my issue:

- Created a file **setupTests.js**
- Placed it inside the **src** folder as **src/setupTests.js**
- Placed the following code inside **setupTests.js**:

```
window.matchMedia = window.matchMedia || function() {
    return {
        matches: false,
        addListener: function() {},
        removeListener: function() {}
    };
};
```

**Note:** Run the **npm test** again and it will resolve the issue (**stop the watch task and restart it**).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to make it work:

```
// fix: `matchMedia` not present, legacy browsers require a polyfill
global.window.matchMedia = (query) => ({
  matches: false,
  media: query,
  onchange: null,
  addListener: () => {}, // deprecated
  removeListener: () => {}, // deprecated
  addEventListener: () => {},
  removeEventListener: () => {},
  dispatchEvent: () => {},
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a clue from the error message:

> matchMedia not present, legacy browsers require a polyfill

This says that some feature is not available while testing and it needs to be implemented somehow to perform the action.

Find a proper [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill) code for `matchMedia` such as [this polyfill](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/blob/master/matchMedia.js).

Then create a new file in `src` folder named `setupTests.js` and paste the polyfill code into the file. React scripts take care that this file will be executed before the tests are run.

Now run tests again. It's fixed. 
[Others](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/742) have had the same issue.